# Backbone view with custom methods

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view

Coming from a Java world I have added custom methods to my view, but for some reason I can't call them inside my View. It seems that Backbone.View.extend does not behave the way I expect it to.

```
  ...
  var TreeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#org-tree',

    initialize: function() {
      eventBus.on("route:change", this.triggerFilterEvent);
      this.listenTo(treeItems, 'sync', this.render);
      treeItems.fetch({
        reset: true
      });
    },

    render: function() {
      ...
    },

    foo: function() {
      console.log("foo");
    },

    triggerFilterEvent: function(name) {
      this.foo();
      ...
    }

  });
  ...
```

Following code will lead to an `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'foo'`.
My other custom method `triggerFilterEvent` being registered as a eventHandler callback works fine however.

1) Why is that?
2) How would I be able to reuse code by declaring a TreeView specific method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `this` in your `triggerFilterEvent` function is referring to the `eventBus` object instead of your view. Try this instead:

```
eventBus.on("route:change", _.bind(this.triggerFilterEvent, this));
```

This is one of the handy Underscore methods available. More info [here](http://underscorejs.org/#bind)

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken the seoncd argument (`this`) in your `bind` call still refers to the `eventBus`, so it still won't work. To use `bind` you still first need to save a reference to the context, per my answer.

Comment: works for me, the binding happens on initialization, at which stage `this` still refers to the view. This seems to be the most elegant solution to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
initialize: function() {
  var self = this;
  eventBus.on("route:change", self.triggerFilterEvent);
  this.listenTo(treeItems, 'sync', this.render);
  treeItems.fetch({
    reset: true
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
initialize: function() {

  var self = this;
  eventBus.on("route:change", function(){
    // use "self" because in this scope "this" refers to "eventBus"
    self.triggerFilterEvent();
  });

  // OR
  this.listenTo(eventBus, 'route:change', this.triggerFilterEvent)

  this.listenTo(treeItems, 'sync', function(){
    this.render
  });

},
```